# Can Subscriptionpublish MQTT to AWS IoT?

Tags: aws-iot, fiware-orion

I would like to publish MQTT notifications from Orion's Subscription to AWS IoT topics.
I am aware that Orion can do MQTT notifications, but I would like to know if it is possible for AWS IoT and what authentication is supported in that case. (certificate? user/pass?)
https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/mqtt_notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT Core supports [multiple authentication mechanism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/client-authentication.html).
The most common used one is x509 certificates.
There is other alternatives, like [custom authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-authentication.html). Where you can use username/password (this has been added to support legacy fleet of devices or devices that cannot handle private key and cert).